# ActionScript reverb algorithms

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, filter, effect

Is there any library , or resources, to start working on some audio filter and reverb algorithms to apply to existing files? (like 'Small Room' effect, and so on).

Comment: The guys from autiotool used to have an open source project, but it seems to have disappeared :( Try googling Andre Michelle

Comment: That library is called tonfall http://code.google.com/p/tonfall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what you're looking for and more, here:

http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/soundfx-out-of-the-box-audio-filters-with-actionscript-3/

**Edit**

It appears that I was wrong about the above set of filters, there is no "reverb" filter in there. After some searching I've found the following:

http://www.kevingoldsmith.com/labs/PBSynth-v1/

Comment: apart the poor documentation, how can i obtain some reverb effect from this library?

Comment: Updated answer, found something better.

Comment: Thank you Ascensio Systems :-)

Comment: If it's the right answer for you please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left!

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160814225514/https://www.kevingoldsmith.com/labs/PBSynth-v1/